# Trying to remove multiple local notifications based on the Identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uilocalnotification

I have an app, that creates users. Each of those users may create an object. I give each user the ability to set a local notification on that object. My naming convention for the identifier for the notification is to use the persons name + the name of the object they created. What I would like to do is delete all notifications when that person is deleted from the App.

I need to somehow loop through all the objects of that person, and use that name to identify the notifications I need to delete.

Here is what I'm trying

```
        // remove local notifications
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let personToSerch = person.name!

        var filterdItemsArray = [String]()

        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in

            print("Count: \(notifications.count)")

            func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
                filterdItemsArray = notifications.filter { item in
                    return item.contains(searchText)
                }
            }

            filterContentForSearchText(searchText: personToSerch)
            print("\(filterdItemsArray.count) count of the filter array")

        }

      center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: filterdItemsArray)
```

It just doesn't seem to be working and my return line throws an error that reads: Value of type UNNotificaionRequest has no member contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if following code works for you.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let personToSerch = person.name!
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
            for item in notifications {
                if(item.identifier.contains(personToSerch)) {
                    center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [item.identifier])
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry im not following your answer, where did idtodelete come from?

Comment: idtodelete is the personToSerch that you want to delete in your case.

Comment: I updated my code to show you what I'm trying to accomplish. I need to find all the notifications associated with that person. There may be more then one, and I should be able to create an array by using the persons name as a predicate for that array.

Comment: Hey, I don't understand why are you needing the filtered array.  'UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["Person_name"])' Doesn't this directly work for you? I guess while scheduling the notification you have added the userinfo which you can directly use.

Comment: The problem I am having is, each person can have multiple entries and each entry can have a local notification. How I am naming them is the personName+NameofEntry. That is why I was looking to filter the array based on the personName, what way I get all notifications starting with that name. Does that make sense?